# How to replace a button in appbar on windows 8 app using HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am new to develop Windows 8 app using HTML/Javascript.

I want to create/remove buttons in appbar dynamically.

For example, I have the following appbar div in html.

```
<div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{placement: 'top'}">
    <button id="button" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
        data-win-options="{id:'button', label:'Button', icon:'add'}" type="button">
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to replace the button triggered by some action, so what I did was replacing the innerHTML of appbar div as follows in js, but what I got was a strange blank square in appbar.

```
var appbar = document.getElementById("appbar");
var html = "<button data-win-control=\"WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand\" data-win-options=\"{id:'button', label:'Another Button', icon:'add'}\" type=\"button\"></button>";
appbar.innerHTML = html;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation for the app bar is to define all of your commands ahead of time and use [`hideCommands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700551.aspx) / [`showCommands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700570.aspx) to show & hide the commands in the appbar itself.

However, if you DO want to create the commands yourself, dynamically, you only need to add one more step to your code:

```
WinJS.UI.process(elementThatYouJustCreated);
```

This will create the win control, and do all the work of getting that control setup.

Comment: Thank you. This perfectly works. I put sample code on gist: https://gist.github.com/3792867

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the value using raw HTML, you should consider using the properties on the [AppBarCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh700497) object.

```
var cmd = document.getElementById('button'); 
cmd.winControl.icon = 'add'; 
cmd.winControl.label = 'Another Button';
```

The AppBar control sample on MSDN shows this in depth:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9/

Comment: This doesn't create the new element; this just edits the one that is already there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to edit a button. This gives me hint to create a new element.